# Is the following convex: $f(x) = \frac{\|\mathbf{Ax}+\mathbf{b}\|^2}{\mathbf{m^Tx}+n}$ over a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

When $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \mathbf{m} \in \mathbb{R}^{n},d \in \mathbb{R}$, is
$$f(x) = \frac{\|\mathbf{Ax}+\mathbf{b}\|^2}{\mathbf{m^Tx}+\mathbf{n}}$$ convex over the convex set $\lbrace \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n | \mathbf{m^Tx} + n > 0\rbrace$. I'm confused on how to approach this considering the norm. Furthermore, I believe the restriction on the set is makes it open, so if I can figure out the norm, I can use differentiability for first order condition of convexity. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\|y\|^2 = y^T y$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is convex over that set. Let's start with Example 24.57 from *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory*, volume 2 by Bauschke & Combettes (which relies on the notion of a perspective function):

> Set $$g\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^m\colon (\xi,x) \mapsto \begin{cases}
> \|x\|^2/2\xi &\text{if}\;\;\xi>0\\
> 0 &\text{if}\;\;x=0\;\;\text{and}\;\;\xi=0\\
> +\infty &\text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Then $g$ is convex.

Next, we can construct the affine operator
$$L\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^m\colon \mathbf{x}\mapsto \left((\mathbf{m}^\top \mathbf{x} +n\right)/2,\mathbf{Ax+b})$$

Finally, we notice that your function satisfies $f=g\circ L$ over your convex set. Therefore $f$ is convex, since it is the composition of a convex function and an affine function (Prop. 8.21, same book).

Comment: Very nice. ${}$